# Is there a downside for using flutter packages?

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

Does using many packages in one app effect performance or  bundle size?

I’m mostly familiar with web and trying to understand more about how it is when it comes to mobile apps.

Comment: What answer do you expect? Because importing sources will obviously increase the bundle size

Comment: Thanks for your very unfriendly comment Rémi. I’m not expecting anything. I’m just trying to understand the technologies I’m using. It’s nothing more than a question that popped into my head for which I didn’t find any answers anywhere.

Comment: Sorry if it felt unfriendly – I genuinely wondered what you were expecting. It could be about many different topics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you are using good healthy packages (like from Google/Dart team and other well maintained packages), there isn't anything you need to worry about.

There is no significant performance issue you'd notice when using more and more packages but yes the size of your app will definitely increase.

You can find the health of package on pub.dev

[image]